# Erro Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getList()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Preciso reaproveitar essa função para que ela use o fetchAll mas também use o num_rows, o problema é que se eu mando retornar o fetchAll ou o num_rows funciona, mas nesse caso eu teria de criar duas funções apenas para uma usar fetch e a outra o rows, porque se mando retornar o execute e tento usar o fetch os nuws dessa maneira da erro: getList()->fetchAll();
quero usar assim:

```
public function getList($table = "produto",$orderTable = "id",$order = "ASC",$limited = 1){
        $this->list = parent::Conecta()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY $orderTable $order LIMIT :limited");
        $this->list->bindValue(":limited",$limited,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        return $this->list->execute();
```

getList()->num_rows ou getList()->fetchAll() usando apenas uma única função, mas dá erro, só funciona se eu criar uma função para cada, exemplo:

```
public function getList($table = "produto",$orderTable = "id",$order = "ASC",$limited = 1){
        $this->list = parent::Conecta()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY $orderTable $order LIMIT :limited");
        $this->list->bindValue(":limited",$limited,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $this->list->execute();
        return $this->list->fetchAll();
```

Comment: que tipo de erro?

Comment: Diz que o metodo getList é indefinido, veja: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getList() in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro não tem nada haver com PDO ou mysql, o problema foi como você chamou o seu método `getList`

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getList()

Para métodos (funções) de classes é necessário o `->` ou `::` (acaso seja estático)

Se estiver dentro da própria class use o `$this`:

```
$this->getList();
```

Se for no objeto:

```
$meuobj = new NomeDaSuaClasse;
$meuobj->getList();
```

E ao invés de retornar o `execute()` basta retornar o `$this->list` e será possivel usar pegar o `num_row` e `featchAll`

```
public function getList($table = "produto",$orderTable = "id",$order = "ASC",$limited = 1) {
    $this->list = parent::Conecta()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY $orderTable $order LIMIT :limited");
    $this->list->bindValue(":limited",$limited,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $this->list->execute();

    return $this->list;
}
```

Fora que não existe num_rows em PDO, o que existe é `rowCount`: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php, então a chamada ficaria assim:

```
$meuobj = new NomeDaSuaClasse;

$x = $meuobj->getList();

$x->rowCount(); //Conta linhas

$x->fetchAll(); //Pega os resultados
```

**"Recomendo"** que siga os exemplos da documentação http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php, não invente da própria cabeça ou fique "chutando" até acertar, siga o exemplo da documentação aprenda e entenda o que é cada coisa no "objeto".

Comment: mas teoricamente eu usando "return $this->list->execute();" ou "return $this->list" deveria ser a mesma coisa, nos dois casos estou mandando retornar o execute, ou isso não é verdade?

Comment: alem do mais mesmo fazendo da forma que vc disse retorna o mesmo erro

Comment: @OtavioFagundes postei os links errados, o correto é do PDO, vou acertar aqui

Comment: @OtavioFagundes execute só retorna true ou false veja http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Agora deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: @OtavioFagundes adicionei alguns detalhes sobre o num_rows

Comment: o fetchAll esta funcionando perfeitamente, só o num_rows que esta me dando esse erro: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::num_rows() in..... eu usava mysqli e nele num_rows funcionava, acho que no PDO deve ser diferente

Comment: @OtavioFagundes foi como eu disse, tem que seguir a documentação, num_rows é no mysqli, em PDO usamos rowCount: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php (inclusive foi o meu comentário anterior já citava este detalhe na resposta)

Comment: acabei de ver suas novas linhas sobre o num_rows e funcionou, muito obrigado, desculpe o trabalho ^^